# Probabilistic independence is analogous to linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

Originally from Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682638.

Let ${V}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a finite field ${F}$, and let ${X}$ be a random variable drawn uniformly at random from ${V}$. Let ${\langle, \rangle: V \times V \rightarrow F}$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form on ${V}$, and let ${v_1,\dots,v_n}$ be non-zero vectors in ${V}$. Show that the random variables ${\langle X, v_1 \rangle, \dots, \langle X, v_n \rangle}$ are jointly independent if and only if the vectors ${v_1,\dots,v_n}$ are linearly independent.

Any suggestion for either direction would be appreciated.

Comment: For one direction, suppose the vectors are linearly dependent. Then without loss of generality we can assume $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k v_k$. Therefore $\langle X,v_n\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k \langle X,v_k\rangle$, i.e., the random variables themselves are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Semiclassical: This shows that joint independence implies linear independence. Do you have any thought on the other direction?

Comment: The observed vector is $X^TV$, so it suffices to show that $AX$ has independent columns whenever $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Mason: The bilinear form is not necessarily the inner product since the underlying field $F$ is not assumed to be real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of any $\ d$-dimensional affine subspace $\ S\ $ of $\ V\ $ is $\ q^d\ ,$ where $\ |F|=q\ .$  Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X\in S)&=\frac{q^d}{q^r}\ ,\\
\mathbb{P}\big(\big\langle X,v_i\big\rangle=f_i\big)&=\frac{q^{r-1}}{q^r}=\frac{1}{q}\ ,\ \text{and}\\
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\big\{\big\langle X,v_i\big\rangle=f_i\big\}\right)&=\frac{q^{r-s}}{q^r}=\frac{1}{q^s}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ r\ $ is the dimension of $\ V\ ,$ and $\ s\ $ the dimension of the subspace spanned by $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\ .$ Thus
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\big\{\big\langle X,v_i\big\rangle=f_i\big\}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}\big(\big\langle X,v_i\big\rangle=f_i\big)
$$
if and only if $\ s=n\ $—that is, if and only if $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\ $ are linearly independent.

Comment: Why does the number of solutions to $\langle X, v_i \rangle = f_i$ agree with the cardinality of an $(r-1$)-dimensional subspace?

Comment: If $\ e_1,e_2,\dots,e_r\ $ is a basis for $\ V\ ,$ then since $\ \langle\,,\rangle\ $ is non-degenerate, the mapping $\ \varphi:V\rightarrow F^r\ $ defined by $\ \varphi(u)=$$\,(\langle u,e_1\rangle,\langle u,e_2\rangle,\dots,\langle u,e_r\rangle)\ $ is an isomorphism. Then $\ \{X\in V|\langle X,v_i\rangle=f_i\}=\varphi^{-1}(\{\alpha\in F^r|\alpha^T\varphi(v_i)=f_i\})\ ,$ which has dimension $\ r-1\ $ because $\ v_i\ne0\ $ and hence $\ \varphi(v_i)\ne0\ .$

Comment: Shouldn't $\varphi(u) = (\langle e_1, u \rangle, \dots, \langle e_r, u \rangle)$ instead?

Comment: I don't think it matters which you choose. However, in my preceding comment I've inadvertently omitted the $\ r\times r\ $ (non-singular) matrix $\ E\ $ with entries $\ \langle e_i,e_j\rangle\ $ from what should have been the equation $$\big\{X\in V\big|\langle X,v_i\rangle=f_i\big\}=\varphi^{−1}\big(\big\{\alpha\in F^r\big|\alpha^TE\varphi(v_i)=f_i\big\}\big)$$

Comment: Do all these follow from the dimension of the solution space of a system of linear equations?

Comment: Yes, precisely.