# Follow-up question on the analogy between probabilistic and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

This is a follow-up on a previous post [Probabilistic independence is analogous to linear independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830740/probabilistic-independence-is-analogous-to-linear-independence).

Let ${V}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a finite field ${F}$, and let ${X}$ be a random variable drawn uniformly at random from ${V}$. Let ${\langle, \rangle: V \times V \rightarrow F}$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form on ${V}$, and let ${v_1,\dots,v_n}$ be non-zero vectors in ${V}$. If we  let $r$ be the dimension of $V$ and  $|F| = q$, show that for any $1 \leq i \leq n$, and $t_i \in F$,

$\displaystyle {\bf P}({\langle X, v_i \rangle} = t_i) = q^{r-1}/q^r = 1/q$, and more generally

$\displaystyle {\bf P}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n (\langle X, v_i \rangle = t_i)) = q^{r-s}/q^r = 1/q^s$, where $s$ is the dimension of the span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.

Comment: WLOG, $V = F^n$. Write $\langle u, v \rangle = (u, Bv) = (B^Tu, v)$, where $B_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$, and $()$ is the dot product. Nondegenerate means precisely that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @Mason: May I ask how does this imply the original conclusions?

Answer (score 0):

By picking a basis for $V$, we may assume $V = F^r$. Write $\langle x, y \rangle = (x, By)$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the dot product and $B_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$. Then
\begin{align}
P(\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}\langle X, v_i \rangle = t_i) &= P(\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}(X, Bv_i) = t_i) \\
&= P(\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}(Bv_i, X) = t_i) \\
&= P((BV)^TX = t) \\
&= P(V^TB^TX = t).
\end{align}
Let $A = V^TB^T$. Clearly if $t \notin R(A)$, then $P(AX = t) = 0$. So suppose $t \in R(A)$. Let $v$ be any vector such that $Av = t$. Then $\{x \in F^r : Ax = t\} =  v + N(A)$ is an affine subspace of dimension $\dim N(A) = r - \dim R(A)$. Since the form is nondegenerate, $B$ and hence $B^T$ is invertible, so $\dim R(A) = \dim R(V^T) = \dim R(V) = s$. Thus $\dim N(A) =  r - s$. The cardinality of any $d$-dimensional subspace of $F^r$ is the same as the cardinality of $\text{span}(e_1, \dots, e_d)$, which is $q^d$. Thus
\begin{align}
P(AX = t) &= P(X \in \{x \in F^r : Ax = t\}) \\
&= \frac{q^{r - s}}{q^r} \\
&= \frac{1}{q^s}.
\end{align}
Thus we reached the unsurprising conclusion that $AX$ is uniformly distributed on $R(A)$.

Comment: For a basis $e_1, \dots, e_r$ of $V$, the event $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n (\langle X,v_i \rangle = t_i)$ corresponds to a system of linear equations $Bx = t$, where $B$ is the $n \times r$ matrix with rows $(\langle e_k, v_i \rangle)_{1 \leq k \leq r}, 1 \leq i \leq n$. $x \in F^r$ is viewed as a column vector, and $t = (t_1, \dots, t_n)^t$. If $s$ is the dimension of the span of $v_1, \dots, v_n$, then the rank of $B$ is exactly $s$ as it has $s$ independent rows, hence the solution space has dimension $r - s$.

Comment: I don’t see how the non- degeneracy condition is necessary here.

Comment: In matrix notation, the system is $V^TB^TX = t$, where the columns of $V$ are $v_1, \dots, v_n$, and $B_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$. The rank of $V^TB^T$ depends on the rank of $B$. For example, if $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ for all $u, v$, then $B = 0$ and the rank of $V^TB^T$ is $0$.

Comment: I think I see where the non-degeneracy assumption is needed now. The matrix $B$ in my comment above is simply the coefficient matrix of the linear system, and non-degeneracy ensures that we don't get $0$ as row vectors (since none of the $v_i = 0$), only then can we safely deduce that $B$ has $s$ linearly independent rows.

Comment: @KKslider The matrix $B$ in your comment is $V^TC^T$, where $C_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$ is the matrix of the bilinear form. The rank of $B = V^TC^T$ is what determines the dimension of the dimension of the solution space to $Bx = t$, and clearly the rank of $B$ depends on the rank of $C$, and is equal to the rank of $V$ if $C$ is invertible.